# Linear Regression with Pytorch - Prediction error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I am using PyTorch to predict the value of a dependent variable.

The source file I am reading for dataset

[image]

As you can see that the Defect Per cent (which is a dependent variable is ~ 0 to 3)

```
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F

SourceData=pd.read_excel("Supplier Past Performance.xlsx") # Load the data into Pandas DataFrame


SourceData_train_independent= SourceData.drop(["Defect Per cent"], axis=1) # Drop depedent variable from training dataset

SourceData_train_dependent=SourceData["Defect Per cent"].copy() # Dependent variable value for training dataset


X_train = torch.tensor(SourceData_train_independent.values)
y_train=torch.tensor(SourceData_train_dependent.values)

X_train=X_train.type(torch.FloatTensor) #convert the type of tensor
y_train=y_train.type(torch.FloatTensor) #convert the type of tensor

# Define dataset
train_ds = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)

# Define data loader
batch_size = 5
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)

#Define model
model = nn.Linear(3,1)

#Define optimizer
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.02)

#Define loss function
loss_fn = F.mse_loss

#Define a utility function to train the model
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for xb,yb in train_dl:

            #Generate predictions
            pred = model(xb)

            loss = loss_fn(pred,yb)
            #Perform gradient descent
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
            opt.zero_grad()
   print('Training loss: ', loss_fn(model(xb), yb))

#Train the model for 100 epochs
fit(100, model, loss_fn, opt)

new_var=torch.Tensor([[5000.0, 33.0, 23.0]])
preds = model(new_var)
print(preds.item())
```

I am getting the prediction for the new_var as 963.40. This value is way higher that he expected value of 0.1 to 3.

Please help

Comment: How is your loss behaving?

Comment: Yes, you should post a figure of the loss over iterations, for both training and testing set. Without it, it is impossible to tell the issue. It could be over-fitting, not learning anything, or even something else. If not for us, do it for you if it is not already the case. It is very helpful to understand what's happening, not only for machine learning but any optimization problem in general.

Comment: For the first few iterations, I am getting below loss but then afterwards it stops showing

_tensor(114055.9766, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
df
tensor(1.5963e+21, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
df
tensor(2.8641e+37, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
df
tensor(inf, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)_

Comment: Predicted : tensor([[-21555.9141],
        [-17211.9043],
        [-17694.4414],
        [-34806.1133],
        [-32997.2461]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)

****************************
Actual :tensor([1.8000, 0.8000, 1.1000, 0.3000, 1.1000])
tensor(6.7490e+08, grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
df